# counting fixed-area closed walks on square 2d lattice

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-walks

I want to count the number $N(n,A)$ of closed walks of length $2n$ on the square $2d$ lattice enclosing a signed area of $A$. These numbers refine $\sum_A N(n,A) = \left(\begin{array}{c}2n\\n\end{array}\right)^2.$  For example $N(2,-1) = 4, N(2,0) = 28, N(2,1) = 4.$  Any help?

Answer (score 7):

This is a difficult question, and the answer depends on what exactly do you want to know.  If you want to know asymptotics for $A$ fixed, then the answer is known for $A=0$ and I would guess it's the same for all fixed $A$.  See refs in [our paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.09419) dealing with generalizations to larger nilpotent groups.

If you want to know the limit distribution of $N(2n,A)/\binom{2n}{n}^2$ scaled appropriately then I would also be interested if this is known (I didn't try to search, but hopefully you did).  A warning: the answer might not be what you expect, cf. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.04042) by T. Budd with a different but vaguely related statistics.

Finally, a few years I was curious about algebraic properties of GFs for $N(2n,0)$ in connection with some earlier enumerative combinatorics work I did ([see here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06636) for references to a lot of other related literature).  Here is the [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A307468) for this sequence (computations were made by J. Pantone).  Our inability to analyze this sequence resulted in my paper with D. Soukup I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank you.  Good to know, though too bad there’s no (known) formula, or even recursion.  My question arises in a similar manner as the one you investigated:  as a count of words in $x, 1/x, y, 1/y$ evaluating to some fixed power $q^k$  in the quantum torus $yx = qxy.$